# How to count maximum number of continuous ones in a dataframe?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a data like this.
There are total 500 categories with daily values, day column has d1-d365 for every category and value is binary column.
I want to calculate longest continuous 1s for every category.

DF:

```
Category     day    value
cat1    d1  0
cat1    d2  1
cat1    d3  1
.   .   .
.   .   .
cat2    d1  1
cat2    d2  1
cat2    d3  0
.   .   .
cat500  d365    1
```

Answer (score 0):

Use [GroupBy.sum](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.GroupBy.sum.html):

```
print(df1.groupby(["Category"])["value"].sum().reset_index().sort_values(by=["value"],ascending=False))
```

The first row will give you the category that has the highest total value.

Comment: Hi, I want to calculate longest continuous 1s for each category.

Comment: You mean, you try to count maximum consecutive numbers of 1 for each category?

Comment: to count maximum consecutive numbers of 1 for each category -  yes exactly